# Can a signal calculate its time period?

Tags: waves, time, signal-processing

I wanted to know if a radio wave has some kind of data for example a kind of packet information (if its a thing) and it gets transmitted and gets received by a receiver, then can it calculate the time it existed from the time of creation to the time it got received by the receiver?

Comment: Not by the nature of EM eaves. But you can send the time of transmitting, and recievert compares it to its internal time. GPS works in this way.

Comment: can't the wave carry a information kind of a timer

Comment: Yeah, it can. But you have to artificially modulate it, eg. you have to make transmitter wich sends signal with encoded timer.  There is no property of EM waves, which can be used as a timer by itself

Comment: thanks bro for telling